# Should we have a state-of-israel tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

We have [zionism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zionism) and I see now [israel-defense-forces](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel-defense-forces), but no [state-of-israel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-of-israel). Questions that are actually about the State of Israel frequently are tagged [eretz-yisrael](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eretz-yisrael) even if they have nothing to do with the Land, *per se*. This strikes me as silly.

Shouldn't we have a [state-of-israel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-of-israel) tag?

Example candidate questions:

- [Does the State of Israel fulfill the coming of the Messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27070/does-the-state-of-israel-fulfill-the-coming-of-the-messiah)
- [Is it Halachically forbidden to go to Israel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68493/is-it-halachically-forbidden-to-go-to-israel)
- [The blessing for 600,000 Jews](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19122/the-blessing-for-600-000-jews)
- [Rav Moshe Feinstein's opinion on the State of Israel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71609/rav-moshe-feinsteins-opinion-on-the-state-of-israel)
- [Which type of government is suitable in the present world according to Jewish Law?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27763/which-type-of-government-is-suitable-in-the-present-world-according-to-jewish-la)
- [Is it a Mitzva Deorayta (Biblical Commandment) to serve in the IDF?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40214/is-it-a-mitzva-deorayta-biblical-commandment-to-serve-in-the-idf)

Comment: The following questions are about things/events/places within the state and _eretz_ but not clearly about either entity. Therefore, when retagging per the answer below, I did not touch these. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76025 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68936 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68812 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/63949 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/63948 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60740 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60546 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51321 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51147 (continued)

Comment: (continued) http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43954 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38727 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37852 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36366 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33920 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25682 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23078 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17227 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17076 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10587 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5471 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3508 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3313 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1955 (continued)

Comment: (continued) Aside from those, I think I've checked every "eretz-yisrael" tag (extant as of my doing it), retagging where appropriate. I've now tagged this question "status-complete".

Comment: @msh210 Thanks very much for shouldering that load! Are you sure that questions that come up specifically (even if incidentally to its status as a State) in the contemporary State of Israel, such as http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76025 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68936 , oughtn't be tagged `state-`? (This probably includes most of the ones you've listed, but I haven't looked through them all yet.)

Comment: (re your comment) No, I'm not sure. I did (I think) retag all the ones that come up in the current state *because* of its status as a state (or because of its government structure or the like), but don't see why the fact that they arise nowadays should result in their being tagged with the state tag. (Nor why it should result in their being tagged with the _eretz_ tag, but I figured _shev v'al taase adif_.)

Comment: There are some in the above list that are about places in the state and _eretz_, like http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5471 (which by the way needs a Bible book tag) and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51147 , which arguably should have **neither** tag.

Comment: Oh, oops, and now I see that one of the ones I didn't retag for the reason mentioned in my previous comment is actually one of the ones you proposed for retagging right in this Meta question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68493

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE: This has been implemented.**

---

I propose that we:

- Remove [israel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel) as a synonym for [eretz-yisrael](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eretz-yisrael), since that just creates confusion now that there are separate tags for the Land and the State (and the People, for that matter).
- Update the tag wiki excerpt for [eretz-yisrael](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eretz-yisrael) to something along the lines of:

  > Questions related to the religiously-defined geographical area, the Land of Israel.

  and add a tag wiki that notes that questions related to the modern State of Israel as a political entity should be tagged [state-of-israel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-of-israel).
- Create [state-of-israel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-of-israel), with a tag wiki excerpt along the lines of:

  > Questions related to the modern geopolitical entity, the State of Israel, and life within it.

  and a tag wiki that notes that questions related to the Land of Israel as a religiously-defined geographical area should be tagged [eretz-yisrael](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eretz-yisrael) and that being about the State of Israel doesn't *ipso facto* make the question on-topic.
- Create a synonym for it: [medinat-yisrael](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medinat-yisrael).
- Apply this tag to all questions currently tagged [israel-defense-forces](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel-defense-forces), and remove that tag, since it's more granular than necessary.
- Consider applying this tag to each question about or relating to the geopolitical entity of the State of Israel and life within it.
- Consider removing [eretz-yisrael](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eretz-yisrael) from each question that bears it and isn't about the Land of Israel *per se*.

Comment: Also consider removing [tag:zionism] and adding [tag:state-of-israel] if and where appropriate.

Comment: good. I see this new topic as very important for halachot

Comment: Please consider adding an entry to http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2216/759